# LAMBDA function as Named Range using Office Script

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I'm trying to automate adding a Lambda function to a workbook's Named Ranges. The formula is sitting in the Name Manager, but the formula returns errors as an invalid formula.

If I copy that formula out and create the same range it works.

I assumed that Excel sends the formula as a weird string or JSON object that doesn't allow it to be recognized as a function somehow, but I can't figure it out.

What am I doing wrong?

Excel Formula

```
=LAMBDA(compare_cell;case1;return1;[case2];[return2];[case3];[return3];
[case4];[return4];[case5];[return5];[case6];[return6];[case7];[return7];
[case8];[return8];[case9];[return9];[case10];[return10];
IF(compare_cell=case1;return1;IF(ISOMITTED(case2);"No case";
IF(compare_cell=case2;return2;IF(ISOMITTED(case3);"No case";
IF(compare_cell=case3;return3;IF(ISOMITTED(case4);"No case";
IF(compare_cell=case4;return4;IF(ISOMITTED(case5);"No case";
IF(compare_cell=case5;return5;IF(ISOMITTED(case6);"No case";
IF(compare_cell=case6;return6;IF(ISOMITTED(case7);"No case";
IF(compare_cell=case7;return7;IF(ISOMITTED(case8);"No case";
IF(compare_cell=case8;return8;IF(ISOMITTED(case9);"No case";
IF(compare_cell=case9;return9;IF(ISOMITTED(case10);"No case";
IF(compare_cell=case10;return10;"Limit reached"))))))))))))))))))))
```

```
Office Script

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
// Your code here
    
workbook.addNamedItem("BREAK", "=LAMBDA(compare_cell;case1;return1;[case2];[return2];
[case3];[return3];[case4];[return4];[case5];[return5];[case6];[return6];
[case7];[return7];[case8];[return8];[case9];[return9];[case10];[return10];
IF(compare_cell=case1;return1;IF(ISOMITTED(case2);\"No case\";
IF(compare_cell=case2;return2;IF(ISOMITTED(case3);\"No case\";
IF(compare_cell=case3;return3;IF(ISOMITTED(case4);\"No case\";
IF(compare_cell=case4;return4;IF(ISOMITTED(case5);\"No case\";
IF(compare_cell=case5;return5;IF(ISOMITTED(case6);\"No case\";
IF(compare_cell=case6;return6;IF(ISOMITTED(case7);\"No case\";
IF(compare_cell=case7;return7;IF(ISOMITTED(case8);\"No case\";
IF(compare_cell=case8;return8;IF(ISOMITTED(case9);\"No case\";
IF(compare_cell=case9;return9;IF(ISOMITTED(case10);\"No case\";
IF(compare_cell=case10;return10;\"Limit reached\"))))))))))))))))))))");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using comma as argument separator within your formula, instead of semicolon, i.e. `LAMBDA(compare_cell,case1,return1,[case2],[return2],...`? Perhaps Office Scripts assumes English-language syntax for formulas, then converts to the locale-specific syntax when created.

Comment: Have you tried incorporating `=INDIRECT()` around `LAMBDA()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if I just call it something else (i.e., not "BREAK") then it works... so I assume that "BREAK" is a reserved keyword in Excel